# Longest portable unsigned integer type

Tags: c

Is it accurate to say that, if you are writing portable C, the longest available unsigned integer type is `unsigned long long`? I'm not looking for a specific number of bits, or even 'at least a specific number of bits', but 'the longest supported by the current compiler and target platform, whatever that may happen to be'.

Comment: For current standards (last 20 years), yes. C89 did not have `long long`. If you're also targeting pre-C99 implementations, stick to `unsigned long`.

Comment: `uintmax_t` is usually the longest, yet some compilers offer longer _extended_ types - playing with C semantics.  No highly portable way to get those.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is it accurate to say that, if you are writing portable C, the longest available unsigned integer type is `unsigned long long`? I'm not looking for a specific number of bits, or even 'at least a specific number of bits', but 'the longest supported by the current compiler and target platform, whatever that may happen to be'.

No. Neither if you're targetting C89, nor if C99+. C89 does not support `unsigned long long` at all, so you're stuck with `unsigned long`. So if you want to support archaic platforms you cannot use it.

And C99 added `uintmax_t` typedef (and `intmax_t` too) which *can* be greater than `unsigned long long`. Naturally `uintmax_t` must have range of *at least* that of `unsigned long long`.

[C99 7.18.1.5](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#7.18.1.5):

> **7.18.1.5 Greatest-width integer types**
>
> 1 The following type designates a signed integer type capable of
>   representing any value of any signed integer type:
>
> ```
> intmax_t
> ```
>
> The following type designates an unsigned integer type capable of
>   representing any value of any unsigned integer type:
>
> ```
> uintmax_t
> ```
>
> These types are required.

This could be an extended integer type that is implementation-defined (GCC for example does not support extended integer types), but **you** wouldn't need to know about it; or, if a future standard implements `unsigned superduper long long` then in the future implementations `uintmax_t` could be a typedef to that.

---

If you really need to support all sorts of compilers, you can use some trickery to create a typedef to the largest portable type like this:

```
#include <limits.h>

#if defined(__STDC_VERSION__) && __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L

/* C99+ */
#include <stdint.h>
typedef uintmax_t mymaxuint;
#define MYMAXUINT_MAX UINTMAX_MAX     

#elif defined(ULLONG_MAX)

/* Some compiler that does not support C99+ but seems to have 
   a macro for unsigned long long for some reason */
typedef unsigned long long mymaxuint;    
#define MYMAXUINT_MAX ULLONG_MAX

#else

typedef unsigned long mymaxuint;
#define MYMAXUINT_MAX ULONG_MAX

#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the `C` standard the compiler is [supporting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_C).

For example, `unsigned long long` is part of [`C99`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) and compilers supporting earlier `C` standards are not guaranteed to have it.
I am not aware of something larger than `long long` on newer [standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types).
For earlier standards `unsigned long` is the largest which is there since at least `C89`.

---

## EDIT

As pointed out in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57269993/5218354) by @AnttiHaapala as well as in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Fixed-width_integer_types) (which I referenced also in the [prior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types) edit), the C99 standard provides you with:

```
TYPE      | MIN VALUE  | MAX VALUE
----------+------------+------------
intmax_t  | INTMAX_MIN | INTMAX_MAX
uintmax_t | 0          | UINTMAX_MAX
```

which provides:

> Maximum-width integer types that are guaranteed to be the largest integer type in the implementation.